# Python DataFrame: Deleting rows by column values that is in my_list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dataframe

Its been about a month with Python and I want to cleanse my DataFrame with one rule. I have df and a list (lst_1) as below. In item2 column, I have values of string. I want to drop any row that values of item2 column is not in my lst_1.

```
df=
    key   sellyr  brand  makrc  item1  item2  
0   da12  2013    imp    apt    furi   dcs    
1   da32  2013    sa     rye    rye    app    
2   da14  2013    sa     NaN    NaN    pro
3   da11  2013    sa     prm    NaN    zdc    
4   da31  2013    sa     grm    wdm    czd  
........

#and my list is below
lst_1 = ['dcs','app','czd','des','sed']

#and my output should be
df_new=
    key   sellyr  brand  makrc  item1  item2  
0   da12  2013    imp    apt    furi   dcs    
1   da32  2013    sa     rye    rye    app    
4   da31  2013    sa     grm    wdm    czd  
........
```

I have .1 million rows of values, so I was hoping to get most efficient code to delete rows. Any ideas?

--------edit-------

One more thing. If I want to sort my df with item1 colums that does not include np.nan value, would df_result2 = df[df.item1 != np.nan] work?

```
df_result2=
    key   sellyr  brand  makrc  item1  item2  
0   da12  2013    imp    apt    furi   dcs    
1   da32  2013    sa     rye    rye    app       
4   da31  2013    sa     grm    wdm    czd  
........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly this should do what you are after:

```
df = df[df.item2 in lst_1]
```

I think it might be better in terms of efficiency if you converted lst_1 to a dictionary though, since the look up happens a lot and lookups are faster in dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_new = df[df['item2'].isin(lst_1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Including answer for second part (NaN) also using "&" operator for 2 conditions:

```
print(df[df.item2.isin(lst_1) & df.item1.notnull()])
```

Output:

```
    key  sellyr brand makrc item1 item2
0  da12    2013   imp   apt  furi   dcs
1  da32    2013    sa   rye   rye   app
4  da31    2013    sa   grm   wdm   czd
```